# BeautifulSoup4での複数ページスクレイピング

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

ページが複数あるサイトのスクレイピングをしようと、下記のようなコードを書きました。
1ページ目を取得して色々処理した後、「e」の入力がなければ2ページ目～...と無限に繰り返すようなwhile文です。

```
import requests
import webbrowser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

targetSite = "http://abc.com/"

def getHtml(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    response.encoding = response.apparent_encoding
    return BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')


pageNum = 1
while True:
    html = getHtml(targetSite+"page/"+str(pageNum))

    ~~~~略~~~~

    inp = input("END?(e) >> ")
    if inp == "e" : break
    else:
        pageNum += 1
```

しかし、2ページ目以降の処理になっても1ページ目のhtmlを取得しているようです。

試しにページ番号を固定にしてみたところ、ちゃんと取得できていました。

```
getHtml(targetSite+"page/"+str(5))
```

自分で調べてみてもよく分からなかったため質問させていただきました。
解決方法がありましたら、ご回答のほどよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 記載されているコードを確認する限り問題はないので、省略されている部分で何らかの間違いをしている（ `pageNum` に再度1を代入など）気がします。

Comment: 取得したテキストなどを配列に格納していたのですが、ループ後にその配列を初期化していなかったという初歩的なミスでした...；；

Comment: @Aroma アドバイスを元に解決したならば、解決に至った情報を整理した上で「自己回答」の形でまとめてもらうとよいかもしれません。

Answer (score -1, accepted):

まず、print関数で値が変わっているか確認しましょう